# is there any relation between the right eigenvectors of $P^\top$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0 &P^\top \\P &0\end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I'm trying to analyze the stationary distribution of a Markov Chain parameterized by some n by n matrix $P$ (top right eigenvector of $P^\top$). While there is a relation between the **singular vectors** of $P^\top$ and those of $\begin{bmatrix}0 &P^\top\\P &0\end{bmatrix}$. However, I couldn't find anything on eigenvectors.

Also, $P\mathbf{1} = 1$ (row sum is 1) and that $P$ is not symmetric.

Any potential leads will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to draw a graph related to your new matrix.
Is there a natural way to partition it's vertices?
What happens after two steps of the chain?

Comment: Note that there's a precise _one-to-one correspondence_ between the eigenvalue decomposition of the symmetric eigenvalue decomposition of $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & P^\top \\ P & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and a singular value decomposition of $P$ (or $P^\top$). If you give me one, I can give you the other. Ultimately, you're interested in learning about a nonsymmetric eigenvalue problem by reduction to a related symmetric eigenvalue problem. I am not aware of any reduction between these problems and believe its unlikely one is known (or indeed one exists).